# Generate netlist from manufacturing files in Altium

Tags: altium, reverse-engineering

I have manufacturing (gerber) files as well as BOMS for a whole bunch of PCB's.

Edit: I have the following available to work with. BOM, gerber, NC Drill, ODB++, pick & place.

I desperately need to turn these into schematics somehow. I've been following this guide: https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/gerber-to-pcb

Steps 4 to 6 really confuse the heck out of me. For instance, how do I find out which layer type is appropriate for each layer? Any clarification on these 3 steps appreciated.

[image]

[image]

after opening layers table again... it updated?

[image]

The layers order
[image]

Comment: Try the Reverse Engineering Stack.

Answer (score 2):

Using Gerber alone won't give you a schematic. At best (!) it will give you a PCB which can be manufactured.
Gerber is a pretty stupid/easy file format. It only shows where there is copper and each layer is a single file whereas the format itself doesn't even say which file is which layer (hence you need to tell AD this manually).
Gerber doesn't even distinguish between copper layers (layers which are electrically relevant), mask layers (soldermask, paste mask, silkscreen) and mechanical layers (which convey additional information but aren't directly relevant to the manufacturing process).

That said, let's see your 3 points:
#4 + #5: You need to tell AD which layer is an electrical layer and which one is not, typically you should be able to derive this information from viewing the layers in Camtastic (the tool that opens if you create a new CAM document). If the gerber files are named like AD does, they will usually have the file ending "gtl, gbl, g1, g2". GTL stands for "Gerber Top Layer", the uppermost layer. GBL is Gerber Bottom Layer, the lowest layer. All layers named G1,G2,... are signal layers in between. GP1,GP2 are plane layers in between - typically in the order of the numbering. GTP and GBP are Gerber Top Paste and Gerber Bottom Paste; GTS, GBS are the soldermask layers. That should be all the information you need.
If the Gerber come from a different processor, the layer name will be in the filename and the ending will be GBR (this is also what the standard requires). Show us the file names and we might be able to help further

#6: In case the design only has through-hole vias there should be only one set. It may be different for more complex designs (uVias, multiple stackups) but this should be straight forward once you have your layers defined.

But again, this will only give you a PCB with no information of the logical side whatsoever.

After additional clarification from OP:

- GBL: Bottom Electrical layer
- GBS: Bottom Soldermask (Mask Bottom)
- GD1: Drill drawing (probably not needed)
- GG1: Drill guide (probably not needed)
- GKO: No idea
- GM29: A mechanical layer, maybe an outline of some sort but could be everything
- GP1: Inner layer 1 (electrical plane layer)
- GP2: Inner layer 2 (electrical plane layer)
- GPB: No idea
- GPT: No idea
- GTL: Top Electrical Layer
- GTO: Top Overlay (Silk mask)
- GTP: Top Paste mask
- GTS: Top Soldermask
- TXT: Could be the NC drill file

There should also be a text file named extref in that directory which explains the layer usage.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated my question. In addition to gerber files and a BOM I also have NC Drill, ODB++, pick & place. One of the layers is a .txt and i'm not sure what that means.

Comment: I added some information but again, this won't give you a schematic. With all the information you wrote here you MIGHT be able to reverse-engineer the schematic but it will be a manual process and you'll have to draw all parts by yourself. Then you will need to place them on the PCB and reverse-engineer from there. Depending on the size and your knowledge of AD we're talking a week to a month of work.

Comment: Would be able to get a netlist as well right? That was pretty much my assumption as well.. I would manually redraw the schematic using the netlist and BOM. Tedious but perhaps the only way. I'm going to give this a try in a bit. After importing the gerbers and drill file Altium seems to have been able to label all of the footprints with their designators.

Comment: That's more than I would have expected to be honest.

Comment: Maybe because the manufacturing files were made using Altium? It even imported the silkscreen text on the PCB. I would post a screenshot but I cannot.

Comment: after opening up the layers table again it seems to have auto-detected the types based on their extension.

Comment: The thing is that you now have a more or less complete netlist in PCB format; but from here to schematic is an interesting journey.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it wants to export to PCB or netlist. I always get "One or more layer types are not defined! For best results, All layer types must be defined", despite having already defined the layer types.

Comment: It's hard to help without the actual project in hand. The second image looks correct, the thirs doesn't. It has the GD1 and GG1 layer in there but those are the drill drawings and not necessarily needed. Yet, it lacks the top layer. The correct layer order would be GTL, GP1, GP2, GBL .. then you have the electrical layers configured correctly

Comment: Understandably. I ended up just deciding not to try and do it this way. I think just designing a new PCB will be a better option.